# Select the first image instead of random

Tags: php

I have the following code to fetch a random picture in a blog post, but I only want to fetch the first one. How can i rewrite the code to solve my issue?

```
    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $row["content"], $var);
    if(!count($var[0]) == 0)
    {
        $randomPic = array_rand($var[0], 1);
        $DOM->loadHTML($var[0][$randomPic]);
        $tag = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($tag as $i) {
            echo '<img src="'.$i->getAttribute('src').'">';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that replacing

```
$randomPic = array_rand($var[0], 1);
$DOM->loadHTML($var[0][$randomPic]);
```

simply by

```
$DOM->loadHTML($var[0][0]);
```

would do the trick. You're explicitly getting the very first element from the array, this way.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be this:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $row["content"], $var);
  if(!count($var[0]) == 0)
  {
      $randomPic = $var[0];    //  Only line I changed is this
      $DOM->loadHTML($var[0][$randomPic]);
      $tag = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');
      foreach ($tag as $i) {
          echo '<img src="'.$i->getAttribute('src').'">';
      }
  }
```